# How to reveal all the information in a local machine opened port with request and python

Tags: python, api, request, localhost, port

I am working with a program in my local machine that serves information in the port 4444 as follows:

```
 http://localhost:4444/info/fileNumber
```

when using requests disabling proxies is possible to parse the answer:

```
{ "fileNumber" : "Doc2018_USA_Europe" }


url_call = 'http://localhost:4444/info/fileNumber'

# disabeling proxies
proxies = {"http": None}
response_dossier_nr = requests.get(url_call, proxies=proxies)
print(response_dossier_nr.ok)
print(response_dossier_nr.text)
fileNumber = response_dossier_nr.json()['fileNumber']
```

The port is open and hence I would like to know if that particular port serves some other data in that port like:

```
http://localhost:4444/info/budget
or
http://localhost:4444/whatever
```

Is there any way to scann the port in a way to get the end points available in the port?

thanks

Comment: You can't get all available URLs that server (on your port) is processing unless there is some URL that server explicitly returns the list of URLs that server is supporting (which to my knowledge is not a common practice).
I might misunderstood your question.

Comment: It looks like you perfectly understood it. So there is no way I can programatically find out that for instance http://localhost:4444/info/fileNumber/author is serving the author of the document and http://localhost:4444/info/fileNumber/date the processing date, or whatever is served. I explicitly have to know that http://localhost:4444/XXXXXXXX address, i.e. that XXXXXXX string